# Cross-platform way to get default directory for Python console scripts?

Tags: python, cross-platform, environment

Is there cross-platform way to get default directory for console scripts the same way one can use `sys.executable` to get path to the Python's interpreter in cross-platform way?

Context:
There's Python script which runs various tools like pip using
subprocess module and it would be good to make sure to run tools that accompany
Python's interpreter used to run this script. Please note that the
script may be run from within virtualenv which had not been activated
– `./venv/bin/python script.py`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [`sysconfig`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sysconfig.html) module provides such API through [`get_path()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sysconfig.html#sysconfig.get_path) function:

Linux:

```
pdobrogost@host:~/tmp$ venv/bin/python -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path('scripts'))"
/home/users/pdobrogost/tmp/venv/bin
```

Windows:

```
X:\>venv\Scripts\python.exe -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path('scripts'))"
X:\venv\Scripts
```

References:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/s3vLkVy2xJk
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2014-February/023867.html

Thank you Ned Batchelder, Oscar Benjamin, Paul Moore and Vinay Sajip for help.